# WebStorm - Jasmine jQuery

Tags: jquery, unit-testing, karma-runner, webstorm, karma-jasmine

I'm quite new to the usage of WebStorm, but it's not working as epected. I had a project in the past, but now I try to recreate it and try to unit test my code.
I'm very new to unit testing JavaScript code.

So, I have a file `karma.conf.js` which contains the following:

```
module.exports = function(config){
    config.set({
        basePath : './',
        files : [
            '../../Resources/External/Bower/angular/angular.js',
            '../../Resources/External/Bower/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
            '../../Resources/Scripts/OfficeUI.js',
            '../../Unit Tests/**/*.Test.js'
        ],
        autoWatch : true,
        frameworks: ['jasmine-jquery', 'jasmine'],
        browsers : ['Chrome']
    });
};
```

So, I do run my tests with Karma using the Jasmine framework. I've included `jasmine-jquery` in order to load fixtures to my HTML code on it.

So, I do have a JavaScript function which toggles a class when you press or release the button:

```
$(function() {
    $('#OfficeUI a.button').on('mousedown mouseup', function(e) {
        $(this).toggleClass('ie-fix');
    });
});
```

Now, I have written a Unit Test which looks like the following:

```
describe("Unit: OfficeUI Elements", function() {
    // Load up the HTML page 'OfficeUI.Elements.Test.html' before every test     is executed.
    beforeEach(function() {
        loadFixtures('OfficeUI.Elements.Test.html');
    });

    it("should do some stuff in this example", function() {
        expect(true).toEqual(true);
    });
});
```

[image]

The image below does show the folder structure of my project.

Now, When I do run my tests, I do receive the following error:

```
Error: Fixture could not be loaded: spec/javascripts/fixtures/OfficeUI.Elements.Test.html (status: error, message: undefined)
```

I've tried to resolve this by changing the `beforeEach` method in the Unit Test like the following:

```
beforeEach(function() {
    jasmine.getFixtures().fixturesPath = '/OfficeUI.Beta/Unit Tests/Pages';
    loadFixtures('OfficeUI.Elements.Test.html');
});
```

I've tried various things in the `fixturesPath` but I keep receiving the same error.

Anyone has an idea on how to solve this?
Any help is highly appreciated.

**Edit: Updated karma config:**

```
module.exports = function(config){
    config.set({
        basePath : '../../',
        files : [
            'Resources/External/Bower/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
            'Resources/External/Bower/angular/angular.js',
            'Resources/External/Bower/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
            'Resources/Scripts/OfficeUI.js',
            'Resources/Scripts/Elements/OfficeUI.Elements.js',
            'Unit Tests/**/*.Test.js',

            { pattern: 'Resources/Unit Tests/*.html', watched: true, served:         true, included: false },
        ],
        autoWatch : true,
        watched: true,
        server: true,
        include: false,
        frameworks: ['jasmine-jquery', 'jasmine'],
        browsers: ['Chrome']
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change in your OfficeUI.Elements.Test.js file the following line:

```
jasmine.getFixtures().fixturesPath = '/Tests/';
```

to:

```
jasmine.getFixtures().fixturesPath = 'base/Tests/';
```

that works fine for me

Comment: I wish I could accept this answer 10000 times. Finally, it's working. Thanks hero :-)

Answer (score 0):

In my karma config file, I have to tell karma that it serves the fixture files for jasmine.

Try to insert the following in the files section of your karma config file:

```
 // fixtures
 { pattern: '../../Resources/Unit Tests/Pages/*.*', watched: true, served: true, included: false },
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still get the thing that the Fixtures couldn't be loaded.

Comment: Ah ok. try to set the basePath in your karma config from './' to '../../' then adapt the file pathes in your karma config file, after that change the fixture path in your jasmine test file, as follow:
    jasmine.getFixtures().fixturesPath = 'base/Unit Tests/Pages';

Comment: Thanks. I've changed it but it still isn't working. Could you have another look?

Comment: The error message says: `Error: Fixture could not be loaded: /Unit Tests/test.html (status: error, message: undefined)` And the code in the unit test is `jasmine.getFixtures().fixturesPath = "/Unit Tests/";` Could this be something with the cross domain like explained on the Jasmine-jQuery page?

Comment: Another small update, in the log of the karma server, I do receive the following: `WARN [web-server]: 404: /Unit%20Tests/test.html?_=1425901581241`

Comment: first is the path in your karma config file correct? 'Unit Tests/**/*.Test.js' - shouldn't it be 'Unit Tests/*.Test.js'?
second: in the jasmine.getFixtures().fixturePath you have to use base, as former shown: 
    jasmine.getFixtures().fixturesPath = "/Unit Tests/";
third: avoid special characters like white spaces in your directory name; on my system everything word when i change jasmine.getFixtures().fixturesPath = 'base/Unit Tests/Pages'; to jasmine.getFixtures().fixturesPath = 'base/UnitTests/Pages';

Comment: I've double checked and the path in the config is now: `'Tests/*.Test.js',` Also, I've renamed the Directory, so name 'Unit Tests' but 'Tests', but still I do receive the same error. You would do me a great favor by checking out the project and see if you manage to get it working on your machine. Thanks in advance: https://github.com/Kevin-De-Coninck/OfficeUI