# jasmine-karma Fixture could not be loaded

Tags: jquery, html, karma-jasmine

I am new to this jasmine and karma. I am trying to execute the following test case. I want to test if HTML element has specific class exist or not? I have added the reference of jasmine-jquery and other required js file.

```
beforeEach(function() {
calc = new MathUtils();
jasmine.getFixtures().fixturesPath = 'base';
loadFixtures('test/test1.html');

});
describe("unit test HTML Elements", function() {

it("just testing of html file", function() {
    expect(true).toEqual(true);
});
});
```

This is my directory structure. I am not sure what I am missing.

[image]

This is my karma config file.

```
       // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
basePath: '',


// frameworks to use
// available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
frameworks: ['jasmine'],

// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
files: [
   // 'node_modules/jasmine',

    'node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.css',
    'node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine-html.js',
    'node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/boot.js',
    'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js',
    'node_modules/jasmine-jquery/lib/jasmine-jquery.js',

    'app/*.js',
    'test/*.js',

    { pattern: 'test', watched: true, served:true, included: false }

],
```

I am getting following error.

```
 Pattern "/Users/harshilkumar/WebstormProjects/testingproj/test" does not match any file.

Chrome 55.0.2883 (Mac OS X 10.9.5): Executed 0 of 1 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0 secs)

Chrome 55.0.2883 (Mac OS X 10.9.5) unit test HTML Elements just testing of sample FAILED
Error: Fixture could not be loaded: /Users/harshilkumar/WebstormProjects/testingproj/test/test1.html (status: error, message: undefined)
```

Any help please?
I do apologize if this is basic error as I am new to this Jasmine and Karma things.

Comment: @kufufra : Can you please help me on this? I know you have provided solution on this thread. This is same but slight different. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28919207/webstorm-jasmine-jquery

Comment: You need to set the base path to e.g. `c:\\path\to\your\webApp`

Comment: @DarrenSweeney: Do you mean I have to set the path in baspath field? in karma config file?

Comment: Yes, here: `basePath: 'c:\\path\to\your\webApp',`

Comment: @DarrenSweeney : I changed the basepath to  `wpp-macbook-pro-m20131126-7:testingproj harshilkumar$ pwd
/Users/abc/WebstormProjects/testingproj` And now also I am getting same error (I am using Mac)

Answer (score 0):

Please add framework 'karma-jasmine-jquery'